# while loop displays less records than it should

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have table in database which looks like this:

category:
id | name

It contains 5 records, but when Im trying to display it using while loop. It displays only 4 records. It doesn't show last record.
Here is my PHP code:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM category";
    $query = mysql_query($query);

    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query); // shows 5 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo .$row['name']."<br>";
    }
```

If I use for loop it displays only 2 records.
Also I noticed that when I use print_r(mysql_fetch_array($query)) it shows me only last record, same with var_dump. Shouldn't it show all records?
Is it something with my code, or with PHP config?
Thanks for any tips

Comment: Do all 5 rows have a `name`?

Comment: remove that first dot after echo, check if $row['name'] is not empty or watch the source to see if you have five `<br>`

Comment: @MarcelKorpel You think that's why I'm getting this error?

Comment: No, that's why I posted this as a comment. But do you see five `<br>`s?

Comment: @ColinMorelli Yes, all rows have unique name. Two of them contains special chars such as ą ę  
No, there is 4 <br> tags

Comment: @user1409508 Are you sure this is your full code sample? Are you calling `mysql_fetch_*` before the while loop?

Comment: Yes, even if I create new document, set db connection and copy this code, it shows one less record. Even if I change datebase or table (Im working on localhost) it shows one less record.

Answer (score 1):

you are making two same variables

use this

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM category";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

   $rows = mysql_num_rows($result); // shows 5 

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
    echo $row['name']."<br />";
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't really make a difference, the value assigned in the second line would override the value in the first.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this type problem i think your last 'name' field is empty for 
checking also  print counter or use print_r example

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($row);
  echo "</pre>;
}
```

Comment: No, all rows have name(unique name). Two of them contains special chars, but even if I delete them, it still shows me one less record than it should.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how it's possible but after I use PDO to select records from my table, problem disappeared.
Thanks for help, especially you Marcel.